# Parametrizing on a curve from one point to another

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am dealing with a simple parametrization problem and I am doing a sanity check for my solution.

Problem
Find the parameterization of the curve that is a portion of the parabola $y = x^2$ that starts at the $(0,0)$ and ends at $(2, 4)$.

My solution
What I did is that I want a curve $r(t)=ix(t)+jy(t)$. I let $x=t$ which implies $y=t^2$. Then I came up with the following equation, using a guess instead of mathematical tools

$r(t)= i(2t)+j(4t^2)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Does this seem correct?
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but why didn't you just use $(t,t^2)$ for $0\le t\le 2$ ?

Comment: I guess I can, I just thought it is more aesthetically pleasing, but thank you so much for the conformation, sometimes I am unsure of my work.

Comment: It is correct though slightly harder than the natural one proposed bt Yves. Yet what you did is nice as taking the parameter in $\;[0,1]\;$ makes things simpler many times.